Equality of probability measures from given integral
Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space. Consider $\Bbb{R}$ equipped with its Borel sigma-algebra, and let $\mu,\nu$ be probability measures on $X\times\Bbb{R}$, with the product sigma-algebra.
Suppose now that for every $A\in\mathcal{A}$,
$$
\int_{A\times\Bbb{R}} r\,\mu(dx\,dr) = \int_{A\times\Bbb{R}} r\,\nu(dx\,dr) .
$$
Can we conclude that $\mu=\nu$?

Easy counter-example: Let $\mu=\mu_1 \times \tau, \nu=\nu_1 \times \tau$ where $\tau$ has mean $0$. Then both sides of your equation are $0$ and $\mu_1$, $\nu_1$ can be any two probability measures.
